# What's the missing preposition in the following sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests

> I could tell she was older than me. Maybe four years [...].

I can't think of the article that I should write in the last part of the sentence (the one that refers to *older*).

Any suggestions?

(Maybe it  should be *Maybe for X of years*?)

Comment: I would just say *Maybe four years older*.  If you don't want to reuse the word "older," you could say *Maybe **by** four years*.  Either would be acceptable in common use, although the second sentence is a fragment either way, because there's no predicate.

Comment: Can you please clearly identify where you think an article is missing?

Comment: Judging by your edit, I think you are asking about a _preposition_, not an article. And the comment left by @RaceYouAnytime is probably your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tell she was older than me...maybe, by almost four years.

Comment: The only other preposition I could think of that made sense was "over", but "by" is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I could tell she was older than me. Maybe four years [**or so**].

Comment: Note also that it could be *Maybe four **or so** years*.